# Can't see bootstrap import

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to develop an angular project and for the project inside the angular.json file, I have defined 2 styles. styles.css and node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css. When I type run ng serve it says it compiled successfully. But when I go to developer tools, inside the head section, there is no style and it gives this warning:

```
`DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of angular.json where you have mentioned the relative path for bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Please provide your code example i.e. how you have configured the angular JSON

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can setup bootstrap for your Angular (7+) project.

You need to first install bootstrap latest version using below command.

```html
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Once you install bootstrap there is bootstrap folder will be created in **node_modules**. You need to configure bootstrap css in **angular.json** file.

```js
 "projects": {
    "ng-base": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng-base",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

Another way you can import bootstrap is from your style.scss file.

```css
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Once you are done with this just **restart the application** by using **ng serve** command. You should see style.css and bootstrap.css in the dev Tools.

Comment: Thank you I used this method it said compiled successfully yet, it gives this deprecation warning when i run ng serve command 

(node:11568) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Angular\new-app\new-app\node_modules\tslib\package.json. Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*". (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created

Comment: Which version of Node js you are using. Please check in Node JS command prompt using node -v command. Also please check your angular cli version and angular version.

Comment: I'm using v15.2.0 version of node JS and 11.0.1 version of angular cli